# Run-Time Error 4605: The ShowHiddenText method or property is not available because this command is not available for reading

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm fairly new to using content controls and I'm designing a Word form for work. The current form has the help text for content controls hidden (I have the option enabled to display hidden controls on my computer); however, I want to make sure users of the form are able to see these controls when they open the form. The issue is that when the help text is not hidden, it prints on the form. Is there a way to set the controls so the help text does not print but it is still visible to users when they open the form?

I tried using the following code, but I ran into issues with it. The code worked on my computer, but when a coworker tested it it caused an error message to appear and I could not figure out why. The single line of code was highlighted but as the code worked on my computer, I'm not sure how to fix it (I am also very new to Visual Basic).

```
Sub AutoOpen()

    ActiveWindow.View.ShowHiddenText = True

End Sub
```

I was hoping that when another user opened the document, they would see the hidden text as if it were not hidden; however, when another user opens the document, they get this error:

> "Run-time error '4605':
>
> The ShowHiddenText method or property is not available because this
>   command is not available for reading."

Comment: The error message is happening because Word is opening the document in the Reading rather than the Print view. That is often the case when a document is opened from email, for example. See if adding this before the line for hidden text helps: `ActiveWindow.View = wdPrintView`

Comment: Thank you, that worked!  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

The error message is happening because Word is opening the document in the Reading rather than the Print view. That is often the case when a document is opened from email, for example.

Adding the following line before the line for hidden text should help, as it will force the document to switch to the Print Layout view:

```
ActiveWindow.View = wdPrintView
```

So

```
Sub AutoOpen()
  Dim vw as View
  Set vw= ActiveWindow.View
  vw = wdPrintView
  vw.ShowHiddenText = True
End Sub
```